# Mysterious "uninstalled processes" using network every time I turn on my computer

Tags: networking, windows-10, process, task-manager

I'm traveling with my dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu laptop and often have fairly limited access to WiFi. When I boot into the Windows side of things (or even wake from sleep, after sleeping a while), I often experience a period of poorer than expected network performance.

Opening task manager, I see via "App History" that something called "Uninstalled processes" typically peg the network for a few minutes after waking. By "peg" I mean that their network use increases in lockstep with anything else I have open that is trying to download continuously. Usually it goes quiet after a few minutes, but it is extremely annoying while it is active. It is worse while tethered to my phone, since then I'm paying real dollars for this activity.

Here's a typical shot of the "App History" list after waking and using "Delete usage history" to bring all counters to zero:

[image: task manager screenshot]

This is some time after the "uninstalled processes" stopped using the network, but initially after wake it was tied for the highest network using process.

This is a new box, and I've uninstalled perhaps a dozen things on it, but none recently and there have been plenty of reboots since the last reinstall.

I'm pretty desperate for any tip on how to track down this rogue process.

Comment: I supose that you have clicked on `Delete usage history` but `Uninstalled processes` Network is still increasing? What antivirus software do you have? I estimate that some process is wrongly put among `Uninstalled processes`.

Comment: Yes, I click that frequently. I am just using the built-in Microsoft defender or whatever it is called in Windows 10.

Comment: This seems to affect [windows 8](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a7389b73-b0f4-4033-b311-8f67428dad48/what-is-uninstalled-processes-on-the-app-history-tab-in-the-task-manager?forum=w8itprogeneral) as well.

Comment: These processes are a great mystery. This [forensics presentation](https://files.sans.org/summit/Digital_Forensics_and_Incident_Response_Summit_2015/PDFs/Windows8SRUMForensicsYogeshKhatri.pdf) unhelpfully explains them as : "Uninstalled Processes’ are all programs no longer on disk (in their original 
locations)". My theory is that this is either Windows or the anti-virus trying to communicate some information about these processes to Microsoft. Try to disable everything under Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Defender, and reboot twice to see if this disappears.

Comment: Yes, I click "delete history"  frequently, and then the uninstalled processes starts growing again. I am just using the built-in Microsoft defender or whatever it is called in Windows 10.

Comment: Did you see my above comment ?

Comment: What about using Sysinternals ProcessExplorer instead of task manager, there is no magical Uninstalled processes group. Then you can update the question with info about process and thread that really uses the network. Also they have Sysinternals TCPView, which would be even better for your purpose, eventually then Process Monitor.

Comment: It could be a virus.

Comment: Sure yes, almost any unexplained behavior "could be a virus" - but it seems very unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 5):

As alluded to in [the forensics presentation](https://files.sans.org/summit/Digital_Forensics_and_Incident_Response_Summit_2015/PDFs/Windows8SRUMForensicsYogeshKhatri.pdf) linked by harrymc in the comments, the *Uninstalled processes* entry is the sum of the statistics for processes whose on-disk executables can no longer be found. The Windows System Resource Usage Monitor, as evidenced by slide 17 of that presentation, identifies programs by their full [Object Manager names](https://superuser.com/a/1096784/380318) (in the case of desktop apps), the service name (in the case of services), or the Windows Store application ID.

Task Manager tries to display the application title for every entry, but that information isn't stored in the SRUM database - it's only in the executable's properties. The theory is that if Task Manager can't find the program's EXE, it lumps the stats into *Uninstalled processes*. We can verify that theory using *science*! Download your favorite portable program that uses a lot of one system resource (e.g. [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), which takes some CPU time if you let it run unfiltered for a bit). Note its entry in the Task Manager accounting. Now close and delete/move the test program, and reopen Task Manager. The resources used have been added to the *Uninstalled processes* entry.

Note that Task Manager *might* consider a program "uninstalled" if its executable is inaccessible for any reason, not just absence. In that case, the program responsible for the activity would reside in a system directory inaccessible even to administrators (by default). You could get more information on it with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx).

Therefore, the network usage is being done by a program that can't be found at the time you run Task Manager. This is almost certainly caused by a desktop application that dumps out or extracts another EXE (e.g. an update checker program), runs that EXE, and then deletes it after it exits. To figure out what's doing it, you could try to parse the SRUM database directly (as described in the presentation), use Procmon's [boot logging capability](https://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool), or try disabling some of your auto-start applications with [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

Comment: @harrymc The program existed at one time, did some activity (which was recorded under the program's path), exited, and was then deleted. The activity was then moved into the *Uninstalled processes* entry.

Comment: @harrymc According to the text on the Task Manager "App history" tab, it shows resource usage since the current date "for current user and system accounts." I suggested using boot logging not because Task Manager shows what happened during boot, but because that Procmon feature can capture things that happened before a user even logs in (which is when the file exists).

Comment: Another possibility would be legacy software, poorly written software, incorrectly patched software, or even malware, that does not identify itself in the registry as good Windows software is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks @BenN. Although I haven't been able to conclusively determine the origin of these processes, your theory makes a lot of sense. I did notice that the component "Windows Upload/Download service" is among the most active users of the network during this time (per the live "Network" column in the "Processes" tab), but isn't reflected in the "App History" tab anywhere (the only obvious omission). So maybe that guy is the culprit.

Comment: Congrats.  Your answer was good enough to be picked as an obvious, bogus LQ answer for audits: http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/564589.  (BTW, I got it right.)  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

These processes are one of the great mystery of Windows and are not documented all. This opens the door to speculation.
For me, undocumented rhymes with parts of Windows 10 that Microsoft
dislikes talking about.

One definition of these processes can be found in this forensics presentation
[SRUM forensics](https://files.sans.org/summit/Digital_Forensics_and_Incident_Response_Summit_2015/PDFs/Windows8SRUMForensicsYogeshKhatri.pdf) that unhelpfully explains them as :

> 'Uninstalled Processes’ are all programs no longer on disk (in their
>   original locations)

Since a program that is no longer on disk is also no longer capable of
having network activity, it stands to reason that this network activity
is *about* rather than *by* these uninstalled processes, and the only entity susceptible
of doing that is Windows or one of its components, chief of which is telemetry,
known for being badly documented and invasive of privacy.

The article [Windows 10 telemetry secrets](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-telemetry-secrets/) defines telemetry :

> Microsoft defines telemetry as "system data that is uploaded by the
>   Connected User Experience and Telemetry component," also known as the
>   Universal Telemetry Client, or UTC service. (More on that shortly.)
>
> Microsoft uses telemetry data from Windows 10 to identify security and
>   reliability issues, to analyze and fix software problems, to help
>   improve the quality of Windows and related services, and to make
>   design decisions for future releases.

My theory is that this is Windows trying to communicate to its secret
telemetry servers the identity of the uninstalled processes.
Or maybe Windows Defender (now an unbreakable part of Windows)
trying to communicate information about these processes.

Try to disable everything under *Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Defender*, and reboot twice to see if this disappears.
However, Windows 10 is known for telemetry that cannot be totally stopped.

If this does not help, try to use a product such as [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437)
to find the IP address of the server this communication is done with.
I assume here that the network activity is toward the Internet,
testable easily by booting without Internet connectivity.
Task Manager may mask the identity of that process under the name of
"Uninstalled Processes", but maybe [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) will tell the truth.

Once you know the IP address of the server, you could use a whois service,
such as [IP WHOIS Lookup](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) to identify the owner of the website.

Comment: Mystery downvoter - identify yourself and explain.